# Changing the printing of a counter only in references

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I have the following problem :  I have a counter (in my case `enumi`) that I want to use for referencing with a different name than when it is appears first. Is there a tool in Tex/Latex to do this?

To be more precise : I want to write this in my document body:

```
\section{Lorem}
\subsection{Ipsum}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{my_item} dolor sit amet
\item consectetur
\end{enumerate}
```

and have the list appear as:

i) dolor sit amet

ii) consectetur

but when using `\ref{my_item}` getting 1.1.i (assuming "Ipsum" is subsection 1.1). So using :

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi} {\bf \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\roman{enumi}~}
```

is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formatting objective may be achieved without loading any extra LaTeX packages (though there is, of course, nothing wrong with loading suitable packages). Just add the following code to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\roman{enumi})} % determine look of label
\renewcommand\theenumi\labelenumi
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumi{\thesubsection.} % "prefix" for cross-references
\makeatother
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\roman{enumi})}
\renewcommand\theenumi\labelenumi
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumi{\thesubsection.}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 

\section{Lorem}
\subsection{Ipsum}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{my_item} dolor sit amet
\item consectetur
\end{enumerate}

\section{Dolor}

A cross-reference to item \ref{my_item}.
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: The same output may be achieved by loading the `enumitem` package as follows:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label*=\roman*),
                      ref=\thesubsection.\roman*)}
```